# Azure storage container deployment - check if blob exists in a public container

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage, azure-rm-template

I am trying to figure out the following:

I have an ARM template that does a whole bunch of stuff.
One of the things is that it creates a blob storage account and container.
The container will be a publicAccess of "blob" (no SAS needed)

What I want to do is, check to see if the blob exists in the container. The container may or may not have been created by the ARM template.

How is it possible to check if the blob exists?

I get an error when trying it:

```
Get-AzStorageBlob : This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission. HTTP Status Code:
403 - HTTP Error Message: This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.
ErrorCode: AuthorizationPermissionMismatch
```

I am creating a storage context and using that like so:

```
$miscFilesStorageContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "<name>"
```

Then trying this:

```
Get-AzStorageBlob -Blob "<File name>" -Container "<containerName>" -Context $miscFilesStorageContext
```

which throws the error above.

My goal is that if a url is supplied via parameters, to upload that file into the storage container created in the deployment script only if the file does not exist already.
Again, the container being created is set to public access so no auth is needed to essentially browse to the file (read only)

Flow:

- Download file locally.
- Create a storage blob context
- Use context to query if blob exists in the storage container
- if not exists then upload the file

Answer (score 0):

Two things to do/check:

1. You enabled public blob access on the storage account. Did you also set the access level for the blob's container to allow public access? (see image below)
2. Did you try `$miscFilesStorageContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "<name>" -Anonymous`?

[image: Container public access]

Comment: The storage account is configured for allowing blob public access. The container is set to public (anon read access for blobs only). Obviously for write access, only want that to happen if I find that the container does not contain a particular blob, then i want to upload/write to it and finally remove that write permission.